# Multi-Groupby (iterate or apply function)

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, pandas-groupby

Posting because this is the first time I have not been able to find an answer to my problem. I've come close, but no dice. I am trying to iterate, for loop or apply a function to a pandas dataframe that is grouped by two columns and the data i want to get to is in a third column after columns 1 and 2 are grouped.

Given Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class':np.random.randint(1,10,100),'Type':np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),100),'Guid':np.random.randint(10000,99999,100)})
```

If I use

```
for name,group in df.groupby(['Class','Type']):
print(name)
print(group.Guid)
```

or

```
for name,group in df.groupby(['Class','Type'])['Guid']:
print(name)
print(group)
```

both get me to the desired output

```
    (1, 'A')
86    86606
89    69999
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
(1, 'B')
0     71982
67    95343
68    84520
75    57036
87    61938
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
(1, 'C')
48    67008
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
(1, 'D')
4     87947
6     98477
13    78437
53    95792
76    66178
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
(2, 'A')
42    47960
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
(2, 'B')
30    69891
82    84436
91    54546
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
(3, 'A')
5     74182
19    12167
35    99939
78    38939
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
(3, 'B')
16    92239
27    25167
41    84245
47    43174
51    50472
Name: Guid, dtype: int32
```

What i would like to do next is some maths or apply a function to 'Guid' within its grouped setting other than the standard mean,std,count,etc. Those work just fine, can even aggregate on them.

```
df.groupby(['Class','Type']).Guid.mean()
Class  Type
1      A       78302.500000
       B       74163.800000
       C       67008.000000
       D       85366.200000
2      A       47960.000000
       B       69624.333333
3      A       56306.750000
       B       59059.400000
       C       31237.000000
       D       61973.000000
4      A       36573.000000
       B       55441.250000
       C       49381.333333
       D       35420.000000
5      A       57252.500000
       B       59267.250000
       C       48885.000000
       D       62163.000000
6      A       43106.800000
       B       46767.500000
       C       23170.000000
       D       31663.000000
7      A       47804.750000
       B       61570.666667
       C       60989.666667
       D       57300.000000
8      A       55890.000000
       B       50629.000000
       D       26312.000000
9      A       13338.500000
       B       49556.000000
       C       66602.400000
       D       58603.500000
Name: Guid, dtype: float64
```

But what I can't figure out is how to apply my own math's or function to 'Guid' when it is grouped by ['Class','Type']. For instance if I wanted to count the number of times the value in 'Guid' changed more than 10,000.

```
df.groupby(['Class','Type']).Guid.apply(function or maths here)
df.groupby(['Class','Type']).agg(['count','mean','std',somefunctionhere]).Guid
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So the question is how to define a function that works on the grouped series ?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406962/find-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-subgroup-column-and-mark-maingroup-based-on-i) was asked earlier, and gives examples of how to define custom aggregation functions that you can use in addition to the built in agg methods.

Comment: @Dark, Yes on the series. I can apply functions on groups, just not a series within a group. The most common errors I get back when I think I'm getting close is KeyError: 0,    Exception:Column(s) my column already selected, or  TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example on how to apply your own custom function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def myfunc(group):
    # You can do whatever you want to the group, just make sure it returns that grouping as dataframe
    group['guid_sum'] = group['Guid'].sum()
    return group

df = pd.DataFrame({'Class':np.random.randint(1,10,100),'Type':np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),100),'Guid':np.random.randint(10000,99999,100)})
group = df.groupby(['Class','Type'])
applied = group.apply(myfunc)
```